# Why is my :enter animation working but my :leave animation isn't?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

This works to nicely bring new rows into my `ngFor` structure, but the `:leave` transition doesn't happen, or it happens immediately. What's missing?

```
trigger('fadeInShrinkOut', [
    transition(':enter', [
        style({
            opacity: '0'
        }),
        animate('.5s ease-out', style({
            opacity: '1'
        })),
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
        style({
            height: '*'
        }),
        animate('.5s ease-out', style({
            height: '0'
        }))
    ])
])
```

The animation is applied like so in the component template:

```
<my-component *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <div [@fadeInShrinkOut]="''"> ... </div>
</my-component>
```

I'm doing the animation on an element interior to the component because it simply didn't work on the component, with the animations in the parent.

It's also worth mentioning that the `ngFor` is using an observable. I wonder if that's not a factor, with the observable being recreated or something else that kills the original array.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is,

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/iwnVFK0vfxAuPOgGmAaN?p=preview**

```
animations: [
      trigger('fadeInShrinkOut', [
    transition(':enter', [
    style({
        opacity: '0',
        height:'0'                       // added for smoothness
    }),
    animate('.5s ease-out', style({
        opacity: '1',
        height: '*',                     // added for smoothness
    })),
]),
    transition(':leave', [
        style({
            height: '*',
            opacity: '1'                 // added
        }),
        animate('.5s ease-out', style({
            height: '0',
            opacity:'0'                  // added
        }))
    ])
    ])
  ],
```

Comment: No change. It shouldn't matter *what* the animations are, right?

Comment: I see that the demo works properly, so there must be some unknown factor in my case. I'll investigate that.

Comment: I didn't understand your first comment.

Comment: The proposed fix (adding opacity styles) didn't improve my result, but it shouldn't matter what the animation types are if they're not working at all.

Comment: This was a bug logged to Github repo long back.

Comment: A link might be very helpful. Thank you.